# What exactly do you do in a chat room?

Tags: support

Just wondering on this and I feel kind of silly for asking this but what do you do in a Chat Room? I notice that on other Stackexchange websites they have Chat Rooms. I gained the privelge to chat in chatrooms a while back now and I really don't know what its about? What are you suppose to talk about? E.g. I went to a Anime and Manga chat room and had no idea what to say. What are you suppose to talk about? Are than any rules I should be aware of, because it just looked like questions that you ask show up there.

Help would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general topic is Anime and Manga, but you aren't limited to that. The only major rule is be nice and treat others the same way you expect to be treated.

We're hoping to see you there :)

Answer (score 6):

Personally I go there to ask about different shows and stuff, I think I asked a couple of days ago - if, after watching episode 1, should I continue with Nisekoi, as I didn't enjoy the first episode.

I don't talk much, but I do stick my head in now and then.

It's really just a general chat room with the other members in the anime stackexchange community - people post pictures, talk about questions that don't really need a meta, and just chat about anime and related stuff [It doesn't even have to be related, there's often programming talk in there too].

The questions that show up there is sent by a chatbot that posts ones that have been newly asked.

If you don't know where to start, why not just introduce yourself and see where it goes from there :)